# IOS display tile view images in UITableView

Tags: ios

[image]

I have 10 images and their description. I have to display it in UITableView. I want to display 
those images in tile view. I am using [this](https://github.com/norsez/BDDynamicGridViewController) library. Here in the sample snap these 5 images are displaying in 2 cells. But i want that, all those images will display in just 1 cell. How can I do that?

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

**[UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)** is the way to go.

`UICollectionView` takes the familiar patterns of `UITableView` and generalizes them to make any layout possible. In your case it will be fairy simple. You will use a standard built-in flow layout to place the tiles with pictures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to do it with UITableView. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible but it will be a hack. And it will for sure take more time to write than just implementing a simple collection view. This is a perfect case for `UICollectionView`. Why does it have to be done using `UITableView`?

Comment: I have to display lots of different data in table cell, that will come from my web service.

Comment: Apart from that my client's requirement is to make the same look n feel like Facebook.